# Is it possible to use DATE_ADD() function after ON UPDATE keyword?

Tags: mysql, alter

I am getting a syntax error from MySQL for the following query...
Query:

```
ALTER TABLE tblName MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 HOUR);
```

Error details:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_ADD(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)' at line 2`

My aim is to store (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 7HR) in updated_at field for every update.

Comment: No. The only thing you can automatically update it to is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: But you can use a trigger to do this, [After Insert Trigger as an example](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/)